# dojo.fx.slideTo Unit parameter for percentage

Tags: dojo

In dojo.fx.slideTo parameter-unit, other than 'px' for pixel, does it has percentage unit?

```
require(["dojo/fx"], function(coreFx){
  coreFx.slideTo({
    node: "someNode",
    top: "40",
    left: "50",
    units: "%"
  }).play();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dojo/fx::slideTo` does not support percentage units. In fact, the documentation is wrong, and it only ever uses pixel unit values. See the code [here](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/fx.js#L411-L420).